# Prisma: Is there a way to resolve SASL authentication failed?

Tags: prisma, next.js13

I just setup `Accelerate` on our db, and after running `npx prisma migrate dev` I get this

error:

```
Error: Schema engine error:
FATAL: SASL authentication failed
```

`Prisma version`
prisma                  : 5.5.2,
@prisma/client          : 5.5.2

`schema.prisma` file:

```
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["postgresqlExtensions"]
}

datasource db {
  provider  = "postgresql"
  url       = env("DATABASE_URL")
  directUrl = env("DIRECT_DATABASE_URL")
}

{..Rest of the models..}
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Could you share your PostgreSQL version and your connection string for `directUrl` (replace the credentials by an example)?

Comment: Hello @Joël - Yes, here is an example of my connection string `postgres://postgres:7b663f1a09e25d5c735cb6324be0d9c81@hxbyvdjnuceveohrwqgo.db.us-east-1.nhost.run:5432/hxbyvdfnxjonhadrwqgo`. My Postgres version is  `14.6-20230406-2`